# decrypt aes ctr cannot get the plaintext but get bytes

Tags: python, encryption, byte, aes

so i have function to decrypt aes ctr. but when i tried to decrypt, the result i got from plaintext is type bytes. is anything wrong with my function? please help me

what i was input

> key : maru000000000000
>
> iv : b'\x19\x89j=-\xed)\xe3\xca\x1b\xde?\x15\x1d$!'
>
> ciphertext : b'\xc6Q\xff\x94\x82\xf8\xd4\xfd\x17'

and the func:

```
def decrypt(key, iv, ciphertext):
    assert len(key) == key_bytes                                                                
    # Initialize counter for decryption. iv should be the same as the output of
    # encrypt().
    iv_int = int(binascii.hexlify(iv), 16)
    ctr = Counter.new(AES.block_size * 8, initial_value=iv_int)

    # Create AES-CTR cipher.
    aes = AES.new(key.encode('utf8'), AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)

    # Decrypt and return the plaintext.
    plaintext = aes.decrypt(ciphertext)
    return plaintext
```

my encryption func:

```
def encrypt(key, pt):
    plaintext = read_file(pt)
    if isinstance(plaintext, str):
        pt= plaintext.encode("utf-8")

    if len(key) <= key_bytes:
        for x in range(len(key),key_bytes):
            key = key + "0"

    assert len(key) == key_bytes
    
    # Choose a random, 16-byte IV.
    iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)

    # Convert the IV to a Python integer.
    iv_int = int(binascii.hexlify(iv), 16)

    # Create a new Counter object with IV = iv_int.
    ctr = Counter.new(AES.block_size * 8, initial_value=iv_int)

    # Create AES-CTR cipher.
    aes = AES.new(key.encode('utf8'), AES.MODE_CTR, counter=ctr)

    # Encrypt and return IV and ciphertext.
    ciphertext = aes.encrypt(pt)
    return (iv, ciphertext)
```

at the first i called encryption func, the plaintext was encode. but when i tried to decode when i call decryption func, it's goes error : `'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xf6 in position 0: invalid start byte`

the result from plaintext : `b'\xf6\x18n:\x8a\xb6\x8e\xb1\xb1'`

what i want to get from plaintext : `SandI2021`

Comment: On my machine, the `decrypt()` method can decrypt the ciphertext generated by the `encrypt()` method. However, the test data you posted seems inconsistent, because the `encrypt()` method returns a different ciphertext for the specified plaintext, key, and IV, namely `b'c(\xff\xcaA|j~\x97'`. Check your test data! BTW, the value for `key_bytes` is missing (assumed as 16).

Comment: i was already check and it same, with the data from encrypt @Topaco

Comment: No, as can be easily proven in two ways: 1. `decrypt()` decrypts the data from `encrypt()` but not your ciphertext, 2. `encrypt()` returns a different ciphertext with your data.

Comment: See online: https://replit.com/@3hK8cL8H24hwiS7/UnequaledSafeConference#main.py

Comment: Ah now i get it. Why when you called func encrypt in decrypt, we can get the right result? @Topaco maybe i should change the encode to decode when try to create new aes ctr cipher in decrypt func?